# put a firestore variable in a polymer template

Tags: firebase, polymer, google-cloud-firestore

Maybe I am over thinking it, but I can't figure out a way to put the results of a Firestore query into a Polymer 3 template.  For example:

```
class MyPage extends PolymerElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        /* somehow set this.users to the firestore users query results */

    }

    static get properties() {

        return {
            users: {
                type: String
            }
        }

    }

    static get template() {
        return html`<div>[[users]]</div>`;
    }
}
```

Using the following code, which does work correctly and print to the console:

```
var all_users;

const setsRef = firestore.collection("users");

setsRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

    var users = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        users.push(doc.data().verb);
    });

    all_users = users.join(", ");

    console.log("All users: ", all_users);

    /* run a function here that sets this.users = all_users */

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

The problem is, I have to run a function from the Firestore results, while the other is a constructor of an object. I would preferably like to have all of my Firebase queries in an external js file, but this async thought process is confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the lifecycle methods to load the users:

https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#element-lifecycle

```
class MyPage extends PolymerElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.users = []
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            users: {
                type: String
            }
        }

    }

    static get template() {
        return html`<div>[[users]]</div>`;
    }

    async ready() {
      super.ready()
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("users").get()
        this.users = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data().verb).join(", "); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use one of the lifescycle methods, then you can fire your own custom event which your `MyPage` element can listen for: https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events

I'm not familiar with Polymer, so the above is untested and what I figure from reading the docs.

Comment: I can't run the MyPage object, Polymer is already running the object automatically when it creates the Polymer Element from the html code.  How do I get the Cloud Firestore code to return the information instead of invoking another function or object?

Comment: How are you calling to your firestore? Express? Firebase functions? Client-side Web?

Comment: I am writing for the web and saving it to the firebase server.  I am calling firestore using the code I provided above.  I include my firebase config information in a js config file that I include in my index.html file.

Comment: That did it thank you! (with the exception that it should be querySnapshot.docs.map)  Really, there should be a cloud firestore web component, but it has not been written yet.